# Rapidxml and UTF8

Tags: c++, utf-8, rapidxml

I am using RapidXML, but I need to write my strings as UTF8, in Rapidxml Manual was explained it supports UTF8 , please tell me how can I use it via C++ ISO ?

Answer (score 2):

The *default* mode of operation for RapidXML is to handle UTF-8 input.  You would have to disable this explicitly using [parse_no_utf8](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_ccde57f6054857ee4042a1b4d98c83b9_1ccde57f6054857ee4042a1b4d98c83b9) to get other behaviour.

> Parse flag instructing the parser to
>   disable UTF-8 handling and assume
>   plain 8 bit characters. By default,
>   UTF-8 handling is enabled.

Comment: UTF-8 re more than 8 bit chars, it can be 2 to 5 8 bit chars, in other words, rapidXML only supports subset of utf-8

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: I don't know what you're referring to. Multiple 8-bit values do indeed add up to a codepoint. But there's no special support necessary. RapidXML doesn't use codepoints; it uses UTF-8 code units. RapidXML may not throw a parse error (I don't know if it does) or other problem if the text is improperly encoded in UTF-8, but it _does_ support it if it is proper UTF-8.